# Provided Grok expressions do not match field value in filebeat (audit.log)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I have configured audit.log in filebeat to store logs in elasticsearch. But i am getting Provided Grok expressions do not match field value.

**and my error.message is:**

Error.message: Provided Grok expressions do not match field value: [\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489) [nb-plugin-audit-2.0.jar:na]]

**and my message is:**

message: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489) [nb-plugin-audit-2.0.jar:na]

Is there any solution to remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

I am now sure what you put in the grok.
But i would test it using [Test Grok](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match) I will edit your question and if you will verify I am correct I could help you more here.
But if your grok value is:

```
[\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489) [nb-plugin-audit-2.0.jar:na]]
```

and you try to catch:

> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489) [nb-plugin-audit-2.0.jar:na]

It indeed wouldn't work.
But again. It is pretty hard for me to understand your situation.